# PHP String in Array Only Returns First Character

Tags: php

For the next week, I'm stuck with a sadly very slow 1-bar EDGE internet connection, so forgive me if I didn't spend quite enough time researching this one, but I just set up a local server for testing code that I would normally test over the internet, and it doesn't seem to be working the same way on my local LAMP install.

The issue is, when I do this:

```
echo strtolower($_REQUEST['page']);
```

the result is this:

```
files
```

However, when I do this:

```
$page['name'] = strtolower($_REQUEST['page']);
echo $page['name'];
```

the result is this:

```
f
```

No, that's not a typo, it consistently returns only the first letter of the string. Doing a `var_dump($page)` will result in `string(5) "files"`, but doing a `var_dump($page['name'])` will result in `string(1) "f"`. I'm using `PHP 5.2.1`.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the code you have posted here is identical to what you're actually doing?

Comment: Where you declared the value of position 'files'?

Comment: Yes, I literally copied and pasted.

Comment: Why do a var_dump($page['files'])? Shouldn't you do a var_dump($page['name'])?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I didn't copy and paste that part, it was actually $page['name'].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question.  `$page` is "files" (as shown by your first `var_dump`).  This could be caused by the deprecated `register_globals`, or a manual approximation thereof.  Given that,

```
$page['files']
```

is "f".  This is because non-numeric strings are implicitly converted to 0 (!).  You can reproduce this easily with:

```
$page = 'files';
echo $page['files'];
```

Comment: I figured it out right before you posted this. Yes, $page was set to files, but I didn't know that. Apparently the issue stems from a PHP setting that was turned on in my local installation but not the remote one which makes it so that if the GET variable "page" is set to files, $page will be set to files as well.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AriX `register_globals` was on I suppose? Exactly the reason why you always need to initialize your variables properly *and* turn `register_globals` off.

Comment: Yes, it was register_globals, which I just turned off. I don't know why it was on in the first place - I don't remember turning it on, maybe it came by default with Mac XAMPP?

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Doing a `var_dump($page)` will result in `string(5) "files"`

This means the variable `$page` is a string, not as you seem to expect an array containing a string. You can use array-like offsets on strings as well to return a single character within the string. Through the magic of type casting `$string['files']` is equivalent to `$string[0]`, which returns the first character.

Your problem is somewhere where you assign the string to `$page`, or somewhere after that were you turn it from an array into a single string. The code you provided should work as-is.

I suppose `$page` is already a string when you assign to `$page['name']`, so you're actually *setting the first character of the string*. Try to explicitly declare `$page = array()`.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue - I obviously didn't read the output of var_dump clearly enough to realize that it was not an array as I had thought, and I thought that register_globals was off (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

To sum up: it's a matter of variable declaration. Before using your array, declare it first:

```
$page = array();
```

Good luck working with strange server configurations.